# "Run with F# Interactive..." context menu option for .fsx files missing in 64 bit Windows

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I know this is not your typical programming question, but it's bugging me...

I just installed the F# 3.1.1 Bundle on two Windows 8.1 machines: One's 32bit and the other 64bit.

I have several F# scripts (.fsx-files) that I use for work, and when I right-click the file in the 32bit system it looks like this:

[image: Run with F# interactive option present]

On the other hand, in the 64bit system it looks like this:

[image: Run with F# interactive option missing]

You might notice the "Run with F# Interactive..." menu entry is missing and the icon is different. I have already tried repairing the Bundle, it didn't help. How can I get the context menu entry into the 64bit Windows Explorer? Both systems are freshly installed.

I hope the answer does not involve some horrible registry hacks... ;)

Comment: Icons are typically driven by file associations. What happens when you try to open them?

Comment: I also just noticed it says "Visual F# Script file" at 32bit and just "FSX File" at 64bit. Do you mean it uses the Visual Studio icon because there is something missing? (When I open them it launches Visual Studio in both cases)

Comment: Not too sure, but I found [this blog article](http://infsharpmajor.wordpress.com/2012/07/06/running-f-interactive-from-windows-context-menu/)

Comment: Did the 32 bit machine already have Visual Studio (Pro, Ult, Web Express, or Desktop Express) installed?  The F# MSI only deploys the VS integration bits if it thinks your system has a supported SKU of VS installed. Icons and file association reg keys are in that part of the package.

Comment: @latkin, yes, I installed VS 2013 Desktop Express on both machines _before_ installing the F# Bundle.

Comment: You should report this as a bug here: https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the installer. They are adding the "Run with F# Interactive..." to the VS 11 handler, but not 12.

> I hope the answer does not involve some horrible registry hacks.

Well, it does require making changes to the registry, I wouldn't call it a hack exactly. The fix is to add the handler to this registry path: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.fsx.12.0\shell`.

So to do this, copy this content into a file named foo.reg (the name doesn't matter as long as the extension is .reg)

*Blah blah blah standard registry disclaimers here about how changing the registry can do bad things and I am not responsible but worked for me.*

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.fsx.12.0\shell\openRunFsi]
@="Run with F# Interactive..."

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.fsx.12.0\shell\openRunFsi\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\F#\\3.0\\Framework\\v4.0\\Fsi.exe\" --quiet --exec \"%1\""
```

Save, then double click to import the registry key. This resolved the problem for me.

Comment: I have a v3.1 installation and simply changing 3.0 to 3.1 in the path string worked flawlessly and everything works as expected.

Comment: In addition to the change @nphx mentioned, I also had to change the default value in `HKCL\.fsx` from `WDExpress.fsx.12.0` to `VisualStudio.fsx.12.0` and the name in the subkey `OpenWithProgids` to the same value. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How should I edit the .reg script for Visual Studio 2017? I tried changing the `VisualStudio.fsx.12.0` to `VisualStudio.fsx.15.0` and changed the path to FSI.exe to be correct. It added things correctly to the registry but it didn't work.